# Gibt es eine Übersetzung von "blackboard bold"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, mathematics

Wie nennt man Buchstaben mit Doppelstrichen, wie sie in der Mathematik für die verschiedenen Grundmengen (natürliche Zahlen, reelle Zahlen usw.) verwendet werden? In der englischen Sprache gibt es die Bezeichnung *blackboard bold*, weil es der Ersatz für Fettdruck ist, wenn man an der Tafel schreibt. Also *Tafel-Fettdruck*?

Answer (score 11):

*Tafel-Fettdruck* wäre ein kleiner Widerspruch in sich, da hier ja nichts gedruckt wird. Aber auch *Tafel-Fettschrift, Tafel-Fett* o. Ä. habe ich noch nie gehört.

In Schule und Universität sind mir nur z. B. *Doppelstrich-N* o. Ä. als Bezeichnung für ℕ untergekommen und vermutlich ist es auch das, was am ehesten verstanden wird.

In typografischer Fachsprache handelt es sich hierbei um [*lichte Schriften*](http://www.typografie.info/3/page/wiki.html/_/fachbegriffe/lichte-schriften-r214) (Englisch: *inline)* oder eine Untergruppe der lichten Schriften – je nachdem, wie man lichte Schriften nun genau klassifiziert (siehe Link). Im entsprechenden Kontext halte ich es für wahrscheinlich, dass diese Bezeichnung von einem Muttersprachler richtig assoziiert wird, also z. B. folgender Satz verständlich ist:

> In Analogie zu anderen Zahlenräumen werden die [Sedenionen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion) mit einem lichten S bezeichnet.

Comment: "da hier ja nichts gedruckt wird" - meines Wissens kann man durchaus Druckschrift verwenden, ohne sie zu *drucken*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass ich das Wort *Druckschrift* auch unglücklich irreführend finde, so ist zumindest mein Verständnis, dass es die Schrift(art) von Druck bezeichnet. *Fettdruck* hingegen impliziert dass die Fettheit ein Ergebnis eines Drucks ist.

Answer (score 7):

The German term, I think, is "doppelt gestrichene Buchstaben". At least that's what the mathematicians I know use to refer to ℕ or ℤ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Dafür gibt es keine deutsche Bezeichnung. Übliche Bezeichnungen sind »Blackbord Bold« oder »Großbuchstaben mit doppelten Linien«. Auch »Mengenbuchstaben« habe ich schon gehört, das wird aber nur von Mathematikern sofort verstanden.

In der Unicode-Tabelle werden diese Zeichen »MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL« genannt.