# Was ist das deutsche Wort für Frakturstil ℤ?

Tags: technical-terminology

Was ist ein deutscher Ausdruck für fette, fette Doppelschlagschrift zur Verwendung auf Tafeln?

```
ℤ
```

Ich werde den Zusammenhang für meine Fragen erläutern, damit eine hohe Qualität entsteht.

Es gibt eine Programmiersprache für den Schriftsatz, die als "MathJax" bekannt ist.

**MathJax** enthält Hunderte von Befehlen und jeder Befehl ist eine Folge eines englischen Satzes.

Wenn wir beispielsweise **MathJax** rendern, ist die Eingabe `\mathbb{Z}` und die Ausgabe `ℤ`.

`\mathbb` ist eine Subsequenz des englischen Ausdrucks "mathematics blackboard".

Ich dachte, ein lustiges Projekt wäre, MathJax zu modifizieren.

In meiner abwärtskompatiblen Variante von MathJax ist es gut, wenn die Leute Dinge auf die alte Art eingeben. Wenn die Leute Dinge auf die neue Art tippen, wird es auch gut sein. Das Ergebnis wäre, dass Menschen für einige der Befehle Teilsequenzen englischer oder deutscher Phrasen verwenden könnten.

- `\mbbb{Z}`
- `\mathbb{Z}`
- `\mathblackboardbold{Z}`
- `\schwarzetafelkühn{Z}`
- `\swztfl{Z}`

was ist ein deutscher Ausdruck für "Kreidetafel doppelt gestrichen fett kühn mutig Schriftzug"?

Comment: Duplikat von: [Gibt es eine Übersetzung von "blackboard bold"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/11467/2594)

Comment: As was pointed out, you can ask questions in English here. In the interest of intelligibility, I highly recommend you to do so. There's not much we can do with "kreidetafel doppelt gestrichen fett kühn mutig schriftzug" or the like.

Comment: Hier soll "fett kühn mutig" wohl für "bold bold bold" stehen?

Comment: Zumindest "doppelt gestrichen" kann ich, dank der Demoschrift, verstehen. Auf englisch würde mir der Rest wahrscheinlich auch nicht mehr sagen.